# lock webcam frames across threads using boost::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to use boost::lock to add thread safety to a camera read, but I am stuck. in Thread A, the frame writer, I have:

.h

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp> 
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp> 
#include <boost/system/config.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_mutex Lock;
    typedef boost::unique_lock< Lock > WriteLock;
    typedef boost::shared_lock< Lock > ReadLock;
    Lock OccamLock;
```

.cpp

```
    WriteLock w_lock(OccamLock); 

//calls frames from camera

            cv::Mat f1 = cv::Mat_<uchar>(images[0]->height, images[0]->width, (uchar*)images[0]->data[0], images[0]->step[0]);


            f1.copyTo(img0);

            w_lock.release();
```

in Thread B, the reader, I have:

.h

```
typedef boost::shared_mutex Lock;
    typedef boost::unique_lock< Lock > WriteLock;
    typedef boost::shared_lock< Lock > ReadLock;
```

.cpp

```
  ReadLock r_lock(oGrab->OccamLock);  //oGrab is the reference to the class in Thread A

                imgs[0] = oGrab->img0;

                r_lock.release();
```

This compiles, but the frames are black. Where am I screwing this up? (I am new to boost, please forgive idiocy)

Thank you.

Comment: Are they black also in Thread A?

Comment: AH, changing `w_lock.release();` to `w_lock.unlock();` seems to have fixed it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh right, good catch. I usually prefer to use scoped locks (taking advantage of RAII), so I rarely need to unlock explicitly.